# Heroku Node.js Discord.js bot deployment failed

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I've encountered quite a little bit issue. I've created a local git repositiory, set up recommended settings as [adviced here](https://github.com/synicalsyntax/discord.js-heroku), and copied all files used by the bot into that repository. Then I added all files, commited changes and pushed into Heroku repository. However without the GitHub repository. I have very important reason for not creating GitHub repository as the bot token is inside a configuration JSON file, which is actually part of the source code. I do not want that token to become visible in public.

However, things didn't quite end up well. The Heroku log says the app crashed because there was no entry point set. I can only guess that there was a mistake in app configuration on the server side, or made mistake while transporting files. Can I recover the app somehow? Or do I need to make completely fresh new app and install all parts one by one independently?

This is what Heroku log says:

```
2018-09-11T13:25:20.012914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-09-11T13:25:18.633506+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 338966c1 by user marpolda@gmail.com
2018-09-11T13:25:18.633506+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user marpolda@gmail.com
2018-09-11T13:25:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-09-11T13:25:26.534154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-09-11T13:25:29.260285+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-11T13:25:29.262057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-09-11T13:25:29.246814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-11T13:25:29.146268+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2018-09-11T13:25:29.160586+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-11T13:25:29.160933+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-09-11T13:25:29.161118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-11T13_25_29_151Z-debug.log
2018-09-11T13:25:31.267503+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-09-11T13:25:33.607355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-11T13:25:33.617718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-11T13:25:33.549320+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2018-09-11T13:25:33.555176+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-11T13:25:33.555439+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-11T13_25_33_550Z-debug.log
2018-09-11T13:25:33.555355+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-09-11T14:02:26.829754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-09-11T14:02:29.197832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-09-11T14:02:32.177929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-11T14:02:32.191335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-11T14:02:32.092366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2018-09-11T14:02:32.099124+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-11T14:02:32.099383+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-09-11T14:02:32.099521+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-09-11T14_02_32_094Z-debug.log
```

I can't seem to locate the root of the issue. This is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "notch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "CZghost",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2"
  }
}
```

And corresponding `package-lock.json`:

```
{
  "name": "notch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async-limiter": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/async-limiter/-/async-limiter-1.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jp/uFnooOiO+L211eZOoSyzpOITMXx1rBITauYykG3BRYPu8h0UcxsPNB04RR5vo4Tyz3+ay17tR6JVf9qzYWg=="
    },
    "discord.js": {
      "version": "11.4.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/-/discord.js-11.4.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-MDwpu0lMFTjqomijDl1Ed9miMQe6kB4ifKdP28QZllmLv/HVOJXhatRgjS8urp/wBlOfx+qAYSXcdI5cKGYsfg==",
      "requires": {
        "long": "^4.0.0",
        "prism-media": "^0.0.3",
        "snekfetch": "^3.6.4",
        "tweetnacl": "^1.0.0",
        "ws": "^4.0.0"
      }
    },
    "long": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/long/-/long-4.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-XsP+KhQif4bjX1kbuSiySJFNAehNxgLb6hPRGJ9QsUr8ajHkuXGdrHmFUTUUXhDwVX2R5bY4JNZEwbUiMhV+MA=="
    },
    "prism-media": {
      "version": "0.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/prism-media/-/prism-media-0.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-c9KkNifSMU/iXT8FFTaBwBMr+rdVcN+H/uNv1o+CuFeTThNZNTOrQ+RgXA1yL/DeLk098duAeRPP3QNPNbhxYQ=="
    },
    "safe-buffer": {
      "version": "5.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer/-/safe-buffer-5.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Gd2UZBJDkXlY7GbJxfsE8/nvKkUEU1G38c1siN6QP6a9PT9MmHB8GnpscSmMJSoF8LOIrt8ud/wPtojys4G6+g=="
    },
    "snekfetch": {
      "version": "3.6.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/snekfetch/-/snekfetch-3.6.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-NjxjITIj04Ffqid5lqr7XdgwM7X61c/Dns073Ly170bPQHLm6jkmelye/eglS++1nfTWktpP6Y2bFXjdPlQqdw=="
    },
    "tweetnacl": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tweetnacl/-/tweetnacl-1.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-cT2LgY2kIGh0C/aDhtBHnmb8ins="
    },
    "ws": {
      "version": "4.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-4.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ZGh/8kF9rrRNffkLFV4AzhvooEclrOH0xaugmqGsIfFgOE/pIz4fMc4Ef+5HSQqTEug2S9JZIWDR47duDSLfaA==",
      "requires": {
        "async-limiter": "~1.0.0",
        "safe-buffer": "~5.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `2018-09-11T14:02:32.177929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-11T14:02:32.191335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-11T14:02:32.092366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start`

 Which means it's looking for a script named "start" in your package.json file. Usually, a "start" script simply means "`node *file_name*`". 
In your package.json file, add 
`"scripts": {
    "start": "node *your main app filename*",
  }`
What about your question of "Installing everything again", i don't quite understand. Try adding the scripts i mentioned, commiting them to git and look if it'll solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue. Also added `worker` and switched the Heroku process to run this dyno instead, which made the app run continuously. Exactly what I need.

Comment: Awesome. Glad i were able to help :)